# Angular Drag & Drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I have 3 nested lists and I want to drag & drop. my problem is when I want to move a level 3 element into another leve 2 element that is in another level 1 element but it doesn’t work

```
    <div class="form-wizard" 
    cdkDropListGroup
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="datas"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)">

        <mat-list>
            <div  [id]="idList" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="datas" *ngFor="let level1 of datas" class="chapitre-expander">
                <mat-list-item> {{level1.id}} - {{ level1.title }}</mat-list-item>
                
                <mat-list cdkDropListGroup cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="level1.children" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="idList" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)">
                    <div  [id]="idListSub" cdkDrag  [cdkDragData]="level1.children"  *ngFor="let level2 of level1.children" class="sous-chapitre-expander">
                        <mat-list-item>
                            {{level2.id}} - {{ level2.title }}
                        </mat-list-item>
                        
                        <mat-list  cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="level2.children" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="idListSub" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)">
                            <div   cdkDrag  [cdkDragData]="level2.children" *ngFor="let level3 of level2.children" class="question-expander">
                                <mat-list-item>
                                    {{level3.id}} - {{ level3.title }}
                                </mat-list-item>
                            </div>
                        </mat-list>
                    </div>
                 </mat-list>
            </div>
        </mat-list>
    </div>
```

I am call this method :

```
dropItem(event: any) {
if (event.container === event.previousContainer) {
  moveItemInArray(
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
} else {
  transferArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
}
}
```

My Datas :

```
    datas: Item[] = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'item 1',
      showChildren: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '11',
          title: 'Sous item 1',
          showChildren: false,
          children: [
            {
              id: '111',
              title: 'sous sous item 1',
              showChildren: false,
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: '21',
          

title: 'sous item  2',
          showChildren: false,
          children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'item 2',
      showChildren: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '21',
          title: 'Sous item 1',
          showChildren: false,
          children: [
            {
              id: '211',
              title: 'sous sou item 1',
              showChildren: false,
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: '212',
              title: 'sous sous item 2',
              showChildren: false,
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: '213',
              title: 'sous sou item 3',
              showChildren: false,
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: '22',
          title: 'sous item 2',
          showChildren: false,
          children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    ];
```

Comment: Please post related code.

Comment: and what is datas?

Comment: I am add my data